# General test to prove a set of points creates a cyclic polygon

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> For $n>4$, is there a way to show that a set of points creates an $n$-sided, cyclic polygon? Or simply, that the set of points are concyclic?

---

All triangles are cyclic. For quadrilaterals, we can use Ptolemy's theorem about the product of diagonals, among others. But, can these tests be extended to arbitrary sided polygons?

The [Japanese theorem for cyclic polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_theorem_for_cyclic_polygons) is one good answer, but I am wondering if there are other simpler ways.

Comment: Just check that for each $k$, $P_1P_2P_3P_k$ is concyclic, by say Ptolemy.

Comment: It's probably good to note that Lord Shark's idea works because of Caratheodory's theorem.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I was expecting to use all the points simultaneously, but that's a very good point too.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is the following.
Take any three points $p_1, p_2, p_3$ and compute the circle $C$ they determine:

---

[image: Circ3]

---

Then check each of the subsequent points, $p_4, p_5, \ldots$
to lie on $C$. You may need to take care with numerical issues.

For how to compute a $3$-point circle, see, e.g., Ed Pegg's
[Mathematica Demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ThreePointsDetermineACircle/).